# Closed form for sum of reciprocals of squares of squarefree numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Is there a closed form for the following series - $$\sum_{n\ is\ squarefree}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is
$$\prod_p \left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \frac{\zeta (2)}{\zeta(4)}$$
where the product is over all primes.

See [euler products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already found the representation you give as a product, and was aware that I can use euler products, but did not see how exactly. I did not know the formula with the "+" sign. Thanks again.

Comment: Welle actually $$\prod \left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right)=\frac{\prod \left(1-\frac{1}{p^4}\right)}{\prod \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)}$$, so in essence we need only the formula with "-" sign.